Canvas Tangent Line and Point Disappears at x = 2.5 Despite Correct Slope Calculation
I'm trying to visualize a curve and its tangent line using HTML5 canvas. The curve is ( y = x^2 ), and the tangent line should dynamically update as I drag a slider for ( x )-values between 0 and 2.5. The slope calculation works correctly, but as I drag the slider near ( x = 2.5 ), the tangent line and point disappear off the canvas.
Here's the relevant part of my JavaScript code:
function drawTangentLine(x) {
    // Current slope and tangent line drawing logic
// Limit x to the range 0 to 2.5
    x = Math.min(Math.max(x, 0), 2.5);  // Ensure x stays between 0 and 2.5

    let y = x * x; // y = x^2 at x
    let slope = 2 * x; // Derivative of y = x^2 is 2x

    // Display the current slope
    slopeValue.textContent = slope.toFixed(2);

    // Calculate the tangent line
    let tangentStartX = x - 0.5; // Start of tangent line
    let tangentEndX = x + 0.5;   // End of tangent line

    // Ensure that the tangent line remains within canvas bounds (x range -2 to 2.5)
    tangentStartX = Math.max(tangentStartX, -2); // Limit to left side of curve
    tangentEndX = Math.min(tangentEndX, 2.5);    // Limit to right side of curve

    let tangentStartY = y - slope * (x - tangentStartX); // Adjust Y for slope
    let tangentEndY = y + slope * (tangentEndX - x);     // Adjust Y for slope

    // Convert graph coordinates to canvas coordinates
    let canvasTangentStartX = centerX + tangentStartX * scale;
    let canvasTangentStartY = centerY - tangentStartY * scale;
    let canvasTangentEndX = centerX + tangentEndX * scale;
    let canvasTangentEndY = centerY - tangentEndY * scale;

    // Draw the tangent line
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(canvasTangentStartX, canvasTangentStartY);
    ctx.lineTo(canvasTangentEndX, canvasTangentEndY);
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#008080'; // Greenish color for tangent
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.stroke();

    // Draw the point of tangency
    let canvasX = centerX + x * scale;
    let canvasY = centerY - y * scale;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(canvasX, canvasY, 6, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#0000FF'; // Blue dot
    ctx.fill();
}

Here's the relevant part of my HTML code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Änderungsfaktor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Änderungsfaktor</h2>
        <div class="slopeDisplay">Die Steigung beträgt: <span id="slopeValue">0.00</span></div>
        <canvas id="curveCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        <div class="slider-container">
            <input type="range" id="xSlider" min="0" max="2.5" step="0.01" value="0">

        </div>
        <div class="description">
            If you drag the tangent line along the curve from \( x = 0 \) to \( x = 2.5 \), the tangent line gets steeper. This also means that the value of the slope becomes greater.
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


I'm using canvas scaling with a defined center and range, and the tangent line should remain visible within the canvas bounds. However, at higher ( x )-values, the tangent line seems to move outside the visible area.
What adjustments should I make to keep the tangent line and point of tangency within the canvas?

And this is the issue.


What scale are you using?

I can't see why CSS is tagged here.

Please create a runnable snippet for easier answerability

Is it deliberate that the tangent line increases in size as you go up the curve? I would have expected a constant length.

What is visible depends on the scale you are using. Without knowing what you want the scale to be we cannot help.
